# Copying the cell and delete column under the certain condidions

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite a beginner in the topic of VBA, that is why I am asking for help.
I need to write a macro that will work more or less like this:

1. If cell A2 is empty, do not let to fill any other cell.
2. If there is something in the A2 cell then:
3. Copy the cell B2 (in which the formula is)
4. Put the value of the B2 cell to the C2 cell
5. Delete Column B and let to file other things in the file.

The macro should work automatically. In the sense, let it "apply" in the step of clicking on cell A2. I have a problem with this as a beginner.

Comment: Please understand that this is not a code writing service. You should at least show the code you already have tried yourself. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is vague, but to get what you described exactly:

```
 Public Sub Process()
     If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
         Range("B2").Copy Range("C3")
         Range("B2").EntireColumn.Delete
     End If
 End Sub
```

Edit

In worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address And Range("A2").Value <> "" Then             
         Range("C3").Value = Range("B2").Value
         Range("B2").EntireColumn.Delete
     End If
End Sub
```

I think it's the closest you can get. It won't fire on every click, but on selection change to A2.

Comment: By "the macro should be automatic" i mean that when I click on A2 the macro will activate

Comment: And in poin 3 and 4 I want to copy and paste the result of the formula, the vaue, not the formula itself.

Comment: Let know if it works. Flag the answer if it does.

Comment: Works great, thank you :)

Comment: @cczarnyy_ flag my answer, so I get rep.

Comment: how I can do that?